# "In my opinion it seems..."

Tags: grammar, meaning

Does the connection of 'in my opinion' and ' it seems' make sense? Here is an example:

In my opinion it seems that the aforementioned process is effective only on a laboratory scale.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both In my opinion and it seems but when you say in my opinion it has the meaning of it seems to me.

It's better to use only one in the same sentence.

It seems ... or In my opinion ...

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of these two phrases together is grammatically correct, but is a little wordy because they both have close to the same meaning. Both 'your opinion' and 'it seems' imply the remaining sentence may or may not be factually correct. The better usage would probably be to use one or the other phrase rather than both together.